# TypeError Bug in Post Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, asynchronous

I am building a very basic Yelp-like API. In my businesses POST route I am able to add a business to my local Mongo DB instance, however, when I make a second db call in the same route to push the new business document's ID into a 'businesses' array in my user collection (to register a business under an owner) I get an error in the function responsible for doing this, saying: `'TypeError: "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"'`
Here's my code:

**The API POST route that adds the business, and tries to register a user**

**The function that tries to add the business ID to the users collection (the offending code)**

```
const { getDb, getUserId } = require('../lib/mongo')

//function to add a new business
exports.userAddBusiness = async function (businessId) {
    const db = getDb()
    const collection = db.collection('users')
    try {
        result = await collection.updateOne({
            $push: { "businesses": businessId }
        })
        return "Business " + businessId + " registered under user " + getUserId()
    } catch (error) {
        return "Failed to register business " + businessId + " under user " + getUserId() + "because " + error
    }
}
```

```
/*
 * Route to create a new business.
 */
router.post('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  //if request passes validation
  if (validation.validateAgainstSchema(req.body, businessSchema)) {
    try {
      const business = validation.extractValidFields(req.body, businessSchema)
      //insert the business into the db
      let generatedId = await addBusiness(business)
      console.log(generatedId)
      //register business under owner and print result
      let res = await userAddBusiness(generatedId)
      console.log(res)
      res.status(201).json({
        id: generatedId,
        links: {
          business: `/businesses/${generatedId}`
        }
      })
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: "Failed to add and register new business" + err
      })
    }
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: "Request body is not a valid business object"
    })
  }
})
```

Here is the error stack when I remove the try/catch blocks from both code blocks:

```
 Business 5eab79e21f9878001963a747 has been successfully added.
api             | (node:25) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
api             |     at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
api             |     at checkForAtomicOperators (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:61:23)
api             |     at Collection.updateOne (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:749:15)
api             |     at exports.userAddBusiness (/usr/src/app/models/users.js:8:39)
api             |     at /usr/src/app/api/businesses.js:50:23
api             |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
api             | (node:25) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Comment: Why don't you post the error stack with line numbers

Comment: @AsifM I have added the error stack to my original post. Please note, the only way to get this stack was by removing the try/catch blocks from my original code (since those do not exit the program and instead capture the error before moving on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though I overlooked the most obvious aspect of the updateOne function: passing in a doc ID... Hopefully when someone searches for an issue similar to this one, they will find this post and quickly fix their mistake.